# Display a div on completion of a video angular 4

Tags: angular

I have the following requirement. When the page loads, run a video. Once the video is completed, show another div using angular 5.

```
<div>
    <ng-container *ngIf="isFirstTimeLaunch === 1" else showFe>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body" *ngIf="displayVideoSource != ''">
                <video #vdShowIntroVideo id="vdShowIntroVideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-4-3" preload="auto" data-setup='{ "asdf": true  }'>
                </video>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-template #showFe>
        <div class="exterior-container">

            <div class="exterior-container-bg" [routerLink]="[ '/pair/detail/' + featuredPair.pair_id]" [queryParams]="{ authCtx: authCtx }"
                *ngIf="featuredPair" (mouseenter)="PlayAudio()" (mouseout)="StopAudio()">

                <div class="flex"></div>
             </div>
    </ng-template> 
</div>
```

**TS code:**

```
runVideo() {

    // let mimeType: string;
    debugger;
    let that: any;

    that = this;
    this.setVideoSource();

    this.videoPlayer.ready(function () {
        const player = this;

        this.play();

        player.on('ended', function () {
            that.isFirstTimeLaunch = 2;
        });

    });
}
```

**Issue 1**

This does not work. What is wrong

**Issue 2**

If I use `ng-container`, instead of `ng-template`, in the else part and check a different value, then the code works but the new div is not displayed. It is only displayed if i do an action like mouse over or a different div that is displayed.

Comment: Is you component set to `OnPush`?

Comment: component tag is defined in the html file , usual way as done in angular. i am not sure i understood.

Comment: thanks for pointing that OnPush. I am new to angular. How to check that

Comment: Do you have at the beginning of your component  `@Component({..., changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush })...` ?
Are you sure your variable is edited correctly?

Answer (score 0):

As Batajus pointed out. I needed to change my component declaration

changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush add

then in constructor . I have the use the ChangeRef class.

and call the detectChanges() method.

I will post the full code.

thanks